# Threads blocked over groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.performOperationOnMetaClass

Tags: grails, groovy, jvm, weblogic, threadpool

We have a Java app that uses Groovy over Grails framework. We recently upgraded from Grails 3.x to Grails 5.x, and seeing performance degradation under load. The application server's CPU utilization has increased by 20%, and upon taking thread dumps, we see that multiple threads are blocked that are running the above method.

Although this method was present in Grails 3.x, the number of threads blocked were less and block time was also almost negligible. I am not able to find the documentation on this method. Appreciate any help.

Comment: What is your specific version of Grails 3.x and 3.x ? What is your version of Apache Tomcat? What JDK you used? What is your development and production operating system and it versions? Show me configuration of Tomcat and your application what related to performance.

Comment: @DoNhuVy - We migrated from Grails 3.3.11 to Grails 5.1.9. And sorry about the wrong tag, we are using Oracle WebLogic 12.x, not Tomcat. This is running on RHEL 7.5. What specific configuration would you like to see?